# How to set DependsOn a resource in another stack?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I need to set this for ECS service.

```
  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: ListenerSSL
```

The thing is ListenerSSL is a load balancer listener resource set on the main template while ECSService is a resource in stack attached to the main template via AWS::CloudFormation::Stack so this doesn't work.

I tried adding `ListenerSSL: !Ref ListenerSSL` line in the parameters section of the AWS::CloudFormation::Stack and then adding:

```
ListenerSSL:
  Type: String
```

in the parameters section of that stack but it says that DependsOn needs a resource not a parameter.

So what is the solution for this?

Comment: I assume you are talking about nested stacks? The only way i see to attach the dependOn to the nested stack resource in the main template. If i have not understood you correctly please explain a bit more what is you goal? Passing the parameter to the nested stack?

Answer (score 0):

`DependsOn` is used for resources in the **same stack**, as CFN will always try to create the resources in the same template in parallel.

If you have to different stacks, you just create first one, and then second one. You can't setup `DependsOn` on resources from other stack.